# CSS Where do I change the text color of the labels

Tags: html, css, graph

The background of my chart is white, and the labels are also white.

What can I do to change the color of the label text please?

```
<div class="switches">
    <div class="col-4">
        <div class="col-md-4 switch-right">
            <div class="switch-right-grid">
                <div class="switch-right-grid1">
                    <h3>TODAY'S STATS</h3>
                    <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit.</p>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Earning: $400 USD</li>
                        <li>Items Sold: 20 Items</li>
                        <li>Last Hour Sales: $34 USD</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="sparkline">
                <canvas id="line" height="150" width="480" color="blue" style="width: 480px; height: 150px;"></canvas>
                    <script>
                        var lineChartData = {
                            labels : ["-1","-2","-3","-4","-5","-6","-7"],
                            datasets : [
                                {
                                    fillColor : "#0099ff",
                                    strokeColor : "#F44336",
                                    pointColor : "#fbfbfb",
                                    pointStrokeColor : "#F44336",
                                    data : [<?php echo $chart1 ;?>]
                                }
                            ]

                        };
                        new Chart(document.getElementById("line").getContext("2d")).Line(lineChartData);
                    </script>
```

Thanks

Pictures below. First is the graph, second is the graph with the text selected to highlight the white text

[image: Graph]

[image: graph 2]

Comment: Which are the labels in above code?

Comment: the ones after the labels : and the vertical ones are automatically assigned

Comment: If have any image then please post here because graph my be generate runtime. So image will help more

Comment: There you go @GokulShinde

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The labels are list elements (**li**) in an unordered list (**ul**). You can target them either by adding a CSS class to the list element or by selecting the **li** elements of the **ul** element of the **.switch-right-grid1** div.

```
div.switch-right-grid1 > ul > li {
    color:#000;
}
```

or

CSS:

```
li.switch-right-grid-label {
    color:#000;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
     <li class="switch-right-grid-label">Earning: $400 USD</li>
     <li class="switch-right-grid-label">Items Sold: 20 Items</li>
     <li class="switch-right-grid-label">Last Hour Sales: $34 USD</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

For li labels

```
.switch-right-grid1 ul li {
  color: black;
}
```

for graph labels try this

```
.sparkline * {
  color: black;
}
```